# React Router v5: history.push() changes the address bar, but does not change the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect a user to a new page if a login is successful in my React app. The redirect is called from the auth service which is not a component. To access the history object outside of my component I followed this example in the [React Router FAQ](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components). However, when I call `history.push('/pageafterlogin')`, the page is not changed and I remain on the login page (based on my `Switch` I would expect to end up on the `404` page). The URL in the address bar does get changed to `/pageafterlogin` but the page is not changed from the login page. No errors appear in the console or anything else to indicate my code does not work.

How can I make `history.push()` also change the page the user is on?

```
// /src/history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();

// /src/App.js
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/login" exact render={() => <FormWrapper><LoginForm /></FormWrapper>} />
                <Route render={() => <h1>404: not found</h1>} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;

// src/services/auth.service.js
import axios from 'axios';
import history from '../history';

const API_URL = '...';

class AuthService {
    login(username, password) {
        return axios.post(API_URL + 'login', {
            username,
            password
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.data));
                history.push('/pageafterlogin');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: have you defined the path of the route in Route component?

Comment: Sorry could you clarify what you mean? `history` is passed to the Router component and the Routes are inside a Switch so even if  `/pageafterlogin` isn't defined it should default to the 404 page.

Comment: If you're using history you can not use `BrowserRouter` you need to import `Router`... If you open the console you'll see - `Warning: <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use import { Router } instead of import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.

Comment: @SakoBu Besides that, are there any differences between `BrowserRouter` and `Router` that would have an impact elsewhere in my code?

Comment: Yes - they take different props: 
`BrowserRouter` - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter
`Router` - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router (you can see it takes the history prop)
There are also `HashRouter`, `MemoryRouter` etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `BrowserRouter`, use `Router` from `react-router-dom`

You could see the [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-do5dgl?file=src/App.js)

```
import { Router, Route, Switch, useHistory, create } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import React from 'react';

const history = createBrowserHistory();


export default function App() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={() => <h1>HomePage</h1>} />
                <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                <Route render={() => <h1>404: not found</h1>} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}


function Login() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    history.push('/pageafterlogin')
  }, [])

  return <h1>Login page</h1>
}
```

Comment: This seems to work now. However, is there anything I need to be aware of now that I am using `Router` instead of `BrowserRouter`? The React Router docs describe `BrowserRouter` as `A <Router> that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.`. Does the plain `Router` not do this?

Comment: Why are you defining history from `createBrowserHistory`? I don't see any reasons unless you're doing the server-side rendering?

Comment: I can't push to the history from outside of a component otherwise. The code that redirects  the user is part of a "service" js file.

Comment: Can't you just give the responsibility back to your `Component.` or better yet pass it as a callback to your APIs. Your services file should limit itself to just calling the API since the name is `service`.

Comment: I could, but `login()` only does one thing (setting the cookie and redirecting to the specific page) on success so I would rather just handle the errors in the component. I am more curious now what the difference between `BrowserRouter` and `Router` is?

Comment: It creates its own "history" when using BrowserRouter, so you don't need to manually provide one. But Router doesn't do that itself, so you need to provide one by yourself. Both works same. Only difference is : when using Router and history, you can do `history.push` from any js file (not required to be a react component).

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a solution to this in 2022 and are using React V18+,
the solution is that React v18 does not work well with react-router-dom v5.

I have not tried with react-router-dom v6 yet, but downgrading to React V17 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I removed `StrictMode` and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import React from 'react';
const history = createBrowserHistory();


export default function MyApp() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}></Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.

Comment: Please follow the documentation this is perfect way to implement.
https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/api/Hooks/usehistory.

Comment: Please [edit] if you want to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I hadn't specified the vesion of 'history'. You need to **use a 4.x version with Router 5.x**. For example, I use React v18, history v4.7.2 and react-router-dom v5.3.3 and it works fine.
Try

```
npm i history@4.7.2
```